# Логика метода bool Enum.HasFlag(Enum enum)

Tags: c#, enum

В MSDN указано следующее:

```
    bool Enum.HasFlag(Enum enum)
    {
        return (thisInstance & enum) == enum;
    }
```

Вопрос: зачем сравнивать результат побитового "И" с искомым флагом, если можно было сделать так:

```
   return (thisInstance & enum) != 0;
```

или так:

```
   return (bool)(thisInstance & enum);//так не работает в С#
```

Чтобы не было явных/неявных преобразований типов? (но при побитовых операциях все равно происходит неявное преобразование к Int32 или Int64)

Просто вот нигде это не объясняется, а вопрос интересный, потому что во всех примерах (даже ручной реализации HasFlag - везде (thisInstance & enum) == enum ).

Так вот хотел узнать, может там производительность выше за счет каких-то встроенных функций CLR или лучше происходит оптимизация?

В данный момент мы создаем дубликат кода!! (ну если уж вообще говорить)

Comment: Проверил - (bool)(thisInstance & enum) нельзя явно преобразовывать Enum к Boolean.

Comment: Convert.ToBoolean(myEnum) - так работает

Comment: Я понял - сделай тест и проверь. Просто думал может есть официальная версия происходящего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, то что вы привели - это спецификация, а не реализация. Поэтому любые соображения оптимизации тут не имеют никакого смысла.

Теперь выясним, чем вообще отличаются сравнение с исходным флагом и с нулём. А отличаются они в случае составных флагов:

```cs
enum Foo {
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
  C = 4,
}

Foo data = Foo.A | Foo.C;
Foo flag = Foo.A | Foo.B;

bool first = (data & flag) != 0; // true
bool second = (data & flag) == flag; // false
```

Сравнение с 0 проверяет установлен ли хотя бы один бит, сравнение с флагом проверяет установлены ли все биты.

Comment: Понял - метод универсальный для Mask&Flag и Mask&Mask,  просто имя у него HasFlag и примеры ихние ручной реализации - тоже для ситуации  Mask&Flag.  Поэтому и возник вопрос, так как двусмысленность тут какая-то.

Comment: А в примерах они четко работают с 1 битом - поэтому я дурак) Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Итак:

> public bool HasFlag (Enum flag);

> Returns true if the bit field or bit fields that are set in flag are also set in the current instance; otherwise, false.

То есть, каждому биту, равному 1 в `flag` должен соответствовать бит 1 в `current instance`. `Current instance` может иметь дополнительные биты, равные 1, они не влияют на результат. Отсюда: `thisInstance & flag` должно быть равно `flag`.

Пример, для упрощения 8 бит. `thisInstance = 11000011, flag = 11000000`. Результат должен быть `true`, т.к. каждой единице в `flag` соответствует единица в `thisInstance`.

`thisInstance & flag = 11000000`, то есть равно `flag`.

Comment: My english very bad)